# Unique values for unique keys in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, unique

I need to keep in the database the meta-data of all the transactions in the system (transaction uuid, source, destination, etc.)

I need to create a view that counts all the unique sources for every destination.
for example, if the src-dst couples of the transactions are:

- dst1, src1
- dst1, src1
- dst1, src2
- dst2, src3

I want to get:

- dst1, **2**
- dst2, 1

This is because src1 and src2 are counted for dst1 (I don't want to count src1 twice.)

How can I do this in Couchdb?

In addition, is there a way to get only the destinations that have more than X unique sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your question is tricky in CouchDB, which isn't designed to cope well with this kind of relational data. If possible, you should look to restructure your documents so you explicitly store a list of sources against each destination. With this, you can simply write a view to map destinations to source counts. Suppose you have a document for each destination:

```
function(doc) {
    emit(doc.id, doc.sources.length);
}
```

The second part of your question is a case of creating a new view and swapping the key for the value, so you can query by the number of sources against each document:

```
function(doc) {
    emit(doc.sources.length, doc.id);
}
```

And then specify a `startkey` of the minimum value:

```
?startkey=5
```

If this isn't possible, you can use a map/reduce function to give you all of the unique rows but you *can't* get it to tell you how many there are.

If all you have in your database is pairs of source and destination (as you suggest), you could write a map function like this:

```
function(doc) {
    emit([doc.destination, doc.source], null);
}
```

Then a reduce function to count the number of unique pairs. In this case, you should be able to simply use the built-in `count` function (if you're new to reduce functions, I recently [wrote a blog post](http://www.ramblingincode.com/building-a-couchdb-reduce-function/) that discusses the basics):

```
_count
```

If you query this view with `group=true`, you will get back a row for every unique destination/source pair. You can get all of the pairs for a particular destination like this:

```
?group=true&startkey=["dst1"]&endkey=["dst1",%20{}]
```

At this point you can simply count the rows in memory. If this is not practical (e.g. you have very large numbers of returned rows), you'll have to look at writing a list function to produce the counts:

```
function() {
    var count = 0;
    while(getRow())
        count++;
    return JSON.stringify({\"count\": count});
}
```

Then call this list function in the same way, for your earlier view:

```
/database/_design/designDocName/_list/listName/viewName?group=true&startkey=["dst1"]&endkey=["dst1",%20{}]
```

This'll give you back a JSON object that tells you how many unique rows there are for the specified destination.

This might all seem clumsy - and it is. Document databases don't deal well with these kinds of relationships and tend to prefer denormalised documents and nesting:

```
{
    "_id": "dst1",
    "sources": ["src1", "src2", "src3"]
}
```